# Jackson - Deserializing JSON to class

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, deserialization

I am calling an endpoint which returns JSON that that looks something like this (in Postman):

```
{
    "Result": {
        "attribute1": { ... },
        "attribute2": { ... }
    }
}
```

The Content-Type header returned by this request is `text/x-json` (as opposed to the usual `application/json`). I think this is causing some problems when trying to deserialize this through Jackson. The POJO for this JSON looks something like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Response {

    @JsonProperty("Result")
    private Result result;

}
```

The `Result` class is from an external library (the same guys who wrote this endpoint). Either ways, when I try to call this endpoint through `RestTemplate.exchange()`, Jackson is unable to deserialize this JSON into a valid `Result` class. I am doing this:

```
ResponseEntity<Response> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, Response.class);
```

Doing `response.getBody()` gives a `Response` object which contains a null `Result` object. Apparently, Jackson is not deserializing the JSON properly. I suspect this is because of the unusual `text/x-json` Content-Type returned by the API.

I also have my `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` object configured to be able to parse `text/x-json` Content-type, but no luck:

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(ImmutableList.of(new MediaType("text", "x-json")));
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(jsonConverter);
```

Any pointers?

Update: I don't know why this didn't work, but I figured out an alternative way - fetching the JSON as `Map` instead of a domain object, which is good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

By default `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is bind to:

- application/json
- application/*+json

We need to add `text/x-json`.

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
List<MediaType> jsonTypes = new ArrayList<>(jsonConverter.getSupportedMediaTypes());
jsonTypes.add(new MediaType("text", "x-json"));
jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(jsonTypes);
```

Now, we should use it in `RestTemplate`:

```
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(Collections.singletonList(jsonConverter));
ResponseEntity<RequestPayload> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, RequestPayload.class);
```

Comment: I already had my `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` object configured in a similar fashion. I edited my question to reflect that. Still, the object gets serialized as null.

Comment: @lebowski, I created small `POC` which works for me when `POJO` model fits to `JSON` payload. Could you confirm that `JSON` payload fits to model and all test passes?

Comment: My JSON should match the POJO's model, but it has some missing properties. However, I have set DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES to false, so it should convert them to null. If you'd like to have a look, here is the JSON I'm trying to deserialize: https://jsonblob.com/c307ea46-4cb8-11e9-a678-23d948b8f634 and here's the external class I am trying to deserialize it to: https://github.com/Internet2/grouper/blob/master/grouper-ws/grouper-ws/src/grouper-ws/edu/internet2/middleware/grouper/ws/coresoap/WsHasMemberLiteResult.java

Comment: Please ignore my last comment. I fetched the whole response as a `Map` which is good enough for my purposes. Thanks.

Comment: @lebowski, if it works for `Map` it means `POJO` model does not fit to `JSON`. I'm glad it works for you, finally.