# Date is getting converted to Long while making a rest call using spring

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-rest

I am passing a date parameter inside an object array as request param while making a rest call using `RestTemplate` to my spring container.

The code is as follows:

```
HttpEntity<SimplePipeServiceRequest> request = new HttpEntity<>(new Object[]{new Date(), 1}, headers);
response = template.postForEntity(uri1, request, String.class);
```

When the request comes to my server, i am receiving date as long. How can i get the date as date ? Why is it coming as long ?

Follwing is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.altra.aligne.controller"></context:component-scan>

<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService">
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="com.altra.middleware.spring.CustomObjectMapper"></bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<!-- RequestMappingHandlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(boolean useSuffixPatternMatch) = Whether to use suffix pattern match (".*") 
when matching patterns to requests. -->
<bean class="com.altra.middleware.spring.ControllerBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
  <property name="converters">
    <list>
        <bean class="com.altra.middleware.spring.GenericDTOConverter"/>
        <bean class="com.altra.middleware.spring.StringToDateConverter"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

and following is the dispatcher-servlet.xml from where i am making the rest call

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <!-- We configure the Jackson mapper to output dates in ISO801 format. This requires adding our
        customized Jackson mapper to the list of Spring MVC message converters. But, if we just add our bean here
        all by itself, it will handle requests it should not handle, e.g. encoding strings.  So we need to add the
        other standard message converters here too, and make sure to put the customized Jackson converter AFTER the
        string converter. -->

        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <ref bean="acmJacksonConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <!-- atom feed requires com.sun.syndication package ...   -->
        <!--<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter"/>-->
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2CollectionHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <!-- marshalling converter requires spring oxm -->
        <!--<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter"/>-->
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Can anyone explain where and how the date is getting converted to long and if i want to avoid it can i achieve it and if i can get the date equivalent again from long ?

I am not familiar with how actually jackson works with spring.

**EDIT**

```
HttpEntity<SimplePipeServiceRequest> request = new HttpEntity<>(AbstractGasService.createSimpleServiceRequest(serviceRequestDTO), headers);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("GasOpsModule");
module.addSerializer(Date.class, new DateSerializer());
module.addSerializer(Object[].class, new ObjectArraySerializer());
module.addSerializer(String.class, new StringSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter dateConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
dateConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
if(!template.getMessageConverters().contains(dateConverter)) {
  template.getMessageConverters().add(dateConverter);
}
response = template.postForEntity(uri1, request, String.class);
```

Still, neither of the serializers are getting called when the **post** is executed.

Thanks !

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to customize `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setDateFormat(DateFormat.getDateInstance());
mapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

But if you can, it is much safer to use `Java 8` `Time` package.

For more info, take a look on:

- [Spring Boot Jackson date and timestamp Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55256567/spring-boot-jackson-date-and-timestamp-format)
- [Problem with timezone in Json response from Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55380919/problem-with-timezone-in-json-response-from-spring)

Comment: Is there a way i can instruct `RestTemplate` to not convert `date` to `long` as it's getting converted to long when it's converting the parameters to an object array.

Comment: can you please paste your Bean class(where you have declared your Date variable), Request and Response that you are sending to RestTemplate?

Comment: @Adithya, you can override message converter used by `RestTemplate`. See this question: [Jackson - Deserializing JSON to class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285941/jackson-deserializing-json-to-class). Or define how `RestTemplate` is created in `Spring` context with right message converter.

Comment: Can i create a message converter for `RestTemplate` which will only consider `date` lets say ?

Comment: @Adithya, I am not sure what do you mean by `date`? `Date` class or `date` part in `date-time` format?

Comment: @MichałZiober - yes. In my object array, if there is a date i want to serialize it to string lets say not long.

Comment: just to elaborate - i am passing an `Object[]` which contains multiple data type objects i.e. `Date`, `String`, `Long` etc. For `Date` specifically, i want to handle this operation i.e. either pass `Date` as is or if that's not possible, pass `Long` (which is currently happenin by default) and on my server convert it back to `Date` object. Btw, i added code as shown in *EDIT* section.